# What is strapdown integration?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, integration

I was reading [this article](http://www.control.tu-berlin.de/IMU-Based_Gait_Analysis) where at a certain point the authors say

> ...
>   First, we consider hinge (or pin) joints. There are several ways to estimate the joint angle of a hinge joint from the measured accelerations and angular velocities. Many of them use **strap-down integration** and some coordinate transformation.

I'm not sure if this term is used widely, but since it's about integration and kinematics, I thought it would have been a good idea to ask it here.

What's exactly strap-down integration? How is it different from "normal" integration?

**Note:** *the context may not help much if you don't know anything about kinematics and the study of human body analysis. Feel free to migrate this question to a more appropriate Stack Exchange's website, if you think this belongs to another website.*

Comment: Have a look at his paper: Quaternion-based strap-down integration method for applications of inertial sensing to gait analysis. DOI: 10.1007/BF02345128

Comment: I suspect it has more to do with utilization of a strap down sensor rather than integration in a mathematical sense.  One of the articles I found "To solve this, a good modeling of the strapdown
inertial integration needs to be given. The core of the strapdown
inertial integration is acceleration rotation from body
frame to navigation frame, which is a nonlinear mapping" https://www.xsens.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Nonliearity_in_Strapdown_Integration_Final.pdf

Answer (score 5):

There are essentially two ways to mount accelerometers for the purpose of navigation:

1. Stabilized platform: an intertially stabilized platform is mechanized using either passive mechanical elements or active controls using gyro feedback and mounted within the body of the vehicle. This maintains a local level reference frame and from this frame one can integrate the accelerometers with respect to the intertial frame.
2. Strap down navigation: By this method the accelerometers are fastened rigidly to the body frame of the vehicle. By this method, the signals together with the gyro signals must be processed and rotated on a moment by moment basis to account for the attitude changes in the vehicle to obtain principle axis, intertial accelelerations, velocity and displacement. This requires 3 axis measurements and either Euler or quaternion transformation mathematics.